# Как получить данные сессии для парсинга asp сайта?

Tags: python, парсер, asp.net, сессия

Задача такова, что имеется у сайта универа страница через которую можно получить рейтинг (оценки) студента. Друг попросил сделать отдельный сайт с более приятным дизайном, который будет получать данные с сайта универа и представлять в красивом виде (подобное уже делал кто то в моей школе, только там была api). Думал просто запарсить его, но проблема - сайт работает на asp, причём видимо кривом. И никак не могу получить данные для сессии, при том еще нет отдельной страницы авторизации, а просто выплывает сверху стандартное окно (https://is.ku.edu.kz/E-Rectorat/ratings/ratingviewing.asp - можете посмотреть, чтобы понять о чём я). Вопрос - как получить данные для сессии, или может вообще не пытаться парсить а как то по другому сделать?
upd: делаю всё на питоне, поэтому желательно всё на нём объяснить

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Два вопроса: 1) Если проследовать по ссылке, то там HTTP Basic Authentication - без пользователя и пароля увидеть ничего не получится у тех, к кому вы обращаетесь за советом. 2) При чем вообще ASP?

Comment: 1) HTTP basic authentification я и хотел показать, ибо обычно даже если ввести неправильные данные и зайти в Network то всё будет видно, но не здесь 2) ASP и C# на котором вся колымага работает обрабатывается только через NTLM я так понял, и сейчас пробую через неё всё